# How can I extend the width of a child div to go beyond the parent div's width?

Tags: html, css

I have several `div`s inside another `div` (let's call it container) and I was wondering if it possible to extend the width of a child `div` to go beyond the width of the container `div`.

It's easier to explain if you could take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/).

Currently, the container `div` has the width of 80% and so do all the child `div`s. I want to extend the width of the first `div` to 100% so that it completely fills the page horizontally.

How would I achieve this?
By the way, the reason I want to do this because I use the grid structure provided by [this](http://www.getskeleton.com/) and it requires that eveything must be included inside a container `div` in order to get the features provided by the structure.

**EDIT:** I just realized the width of the container `div` is specified in px, and not in % as in the jsfiddle example. So setting the width of the child `div` to 120% does not guarantee to fill the page horizontally. How should I approach my problem? The only way I can think of right now is to get the width of screen in px, but I don't think that is possible in CSS.

Comment: Please add the code to this question that correctly shows the problem. What _is_ the width of the container in `px` then?

Comment: Hi, the CSS for the container `div` is `{position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }`. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't do this but it seems to work:

```
#greendiv {
  width:120%;
  margin-left:-10%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/9/).

Why can't the `#greendiv` be before the `.container` or some other wrapper `div`?

---

Edit. Turn you thinking upside down (not really, just make a custom container inside mandatory container, here the `.yellowdiv`s are custom containers and the `#greendiv` is the full width container inside container):

```
.container {
  width: 100%;//or some amount of pixels and the yellow divs follow that setting
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.yellowdiv {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#greendiv {
  background-color: green;
}
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/26/).

Comment: Hi, this works! However, I realized that the width of the container is actually based on px... So specifying the width as 120% wouldn't work. How can I extend it so that it completely fills the page horizontally? I may need to get the width of a screen in px, but I don't think that is possible in CSS. For the reason why the `#greendiv` can't go outside, please read the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: @cookiemonster You can define the `container` width in pixels and the 120 % still works. It's percent of the `container`'s width value, not exact value (but you may have to test/calculate to get the numbers correct). If everything has to be inside the container please consider making some changes. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, I do not want to change the width of container to 100% as I'd like to have some margins on both left and right sides for better visual experience. This container `div` contains the whole contents of my page. Is there are workaround? Or maybe I am just using the grid structure wrongly...

Comment: @cookiemonster You don't have to set the width to 100 %. It can be 960 px if you want to. Just make the `.yellowdiv`s to 80 % width. This Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/28/) illustrates the `.custom_container` concept more clearly but you don't actually need the `.custom_container` `div` as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/30/

Comment: Just made an edit, but I realized it was wrong and I would like to remove it.  Anyone know how?

Comment: this works! check my code here, I'm using this margin-left to display a 'drawer' which when draw the 'drawer' out, it goes beyond the container's left side boundary: http://planetsnippets.com/view?snippet=ahFzfnBsYW5ldC1zbmlwcGV0c3IjCxIEVXNlciIFamFjb2IMCxIHU25pcHBldBiAgICAsO2GCgw

Answer (score 4):

If the parent container is centrally-aligned, you can use negative margins on both left and right sides:

```
#greendiv {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 -12.5%;
}
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/12/

Comment: this is nice I didn't know about negative margins. However, what should I do if the width of the container `div` is defined in px? What value should I use for the margins so that it guarantees to fill the page horizontally?

Comment: If that is the case, you will have to rely on a JS-based solution. It is a little more complicated that CSS because you will have to recalculate the margins when the `.resize()` event is triggered :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:visible` to your parent div which is `.container`.

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow:visible;
}

#greendiv {
    background-color: green;
    width:500px;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CtsTQ/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Well I got what you asked for by doing this:

```
#greendiv {
   background-color: green;
   width: 140%;
   margin-left: -20%;
}
```

But this is not a good practice I think...

Comment: The easiest way to do this is moving that div out of the container and just use the width:100%

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd like to do if I could... But it is important that I keep it inside because if I don't, the `div` does not get resized on mobile devices. This effect is provided by the grid structure I use on the site I posted in my question.

Comment: If your width is set to 100% it normally will get resized :)

Answer (score 0):

Its usually not a good idea to extend stuff beyond wrapper containers but if I had to do it I would most definitely use relative positioning like this.

```
#greendiv {
    position:relative;
    left:-10%;
    width:120%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

You could also use other units like `px` to achieve more precise results.